# Avoid evaluation of script arguments as files [BASH, LINUX]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

As passing arguments to a self made script, I noted they got evaluated by the file-system if that mach, otherwise, just passed as argument. And that is not the behaviour I'm hopping for

giving that code

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array_arg 

#build the array of arguments
while test -n "$1"; do  array_arg+=( "$1" ); shift
done

#test there is some arguments
if test ${#array_arg[@]} -eq 0; then echo  "ERROR no arguments"
fi

#running resume
echo "number of elements:: ${#array_arg[@]}"

for ((i = 0; i < ${#array_arg[@]}; i++   )); do echo "$i>> ${array_arg[i]}"
done
```

I will expect that same list of arguments I pass, I will have into the array_arg array

but, if any argument has a wildcard, and match a file, it get resolve with the name of the file/s

lets see an example :

[image]

let's observe, the second argument

> file2*

how in the instruction

```
array_arg+=( "$1" )
```

adds two filenames to the array, instead of the value of $1

while the last argument, do not get changed/resolved/whatever...

**Needless to say, I need the arguments as passed to the script, not evaluated**

Comment: If you don't want the sell to expand your arguments, quote them.

Answer (score 0):

```
./test.sh "file1" "file2" "file3"
```

This will run fine.